# Is this integral answer 1 ?? However wolfram alpha tells me 1/3 ...

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is the answer "1" right ?? But the answers on [the integral calculators](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%2B2%29%5E2+dx+from+1+to+infty) tell $\frac{1}{3}$. Please help me.
$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{(x+2)^2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rendered $u=x+2$ to get $\int(1/u^2)du=-(1/u)+C$, you may have forgotten to do either one of two things:

- If you keep the antiderivative in terms of $u$, the limits on the integrand must be values of $u=x+2$, thus $x=1$ means $u=3$ for the lower limit.
- If you use back substitution to render the antiderivative as $-(1/(x+2))+C$, then the value of $-1/(x+2)$ at $x=1$ is $-1/3$ rather than $-1/1$.

Either way, $1/3$ is the correct value of the definite integral.